# cakephp 2.6 retrieving data from database

Tags: php, cakephp

Here is my function edit in cakephp controller:

```
public function edit($id = null) { 
if ($this->request->is('get')) {
            $this->request->data = $this->Topic->findById($id);
        }
...
```

First problem is that the parameter id passed to function is of type string not integer.
Second is that,in the database there is a topic with id = 14,and both these codes retrieve same result,i don't understand why:

```
http://localhost/cakephp1/topics/edit/14
http://localhost/cakephp1/topics/edit/14anyCharactersHere
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameters being passed by the URL will of course by of type string because a URL is a string.

Assuming your `id` column in your database is integer Cake will cast the parameter passed to `findById()` to an integer: `(int)"14"` and `(int)"14anyCharactersHere"` both result in `14`. Therefore, both URLs in your question will result in the same data being pulled from the database.

If you want to make sure that `$id` contains only an integer use [`ctype_digit()`](http://php.net/ctype_digit):-

```
if (ctype_digit($id) === true) {
    // Is integer
}
```